# how to create an API call that can add or delete only one entry in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a very typical datamodel with `User`s grouped in `Team`s

This is my first time with DRF (and with REST actually)

I have defined my serializers, and end up with the following URL's - keeping just the gist of it

- `/api/teams/`
- `/api/teams/<pk>`
- `/api/users/`
- `/api/users/<pk>/`

At this point I can change the actual set of users in a team; however it feels like the only to do that is by issuing **2 API calls**, first one to get the current content (the list of user ids in the team), start from that to manually add or remove ids, and send a second API call to replace the user_ids list in the team instance

What I need instead is an API entrypoint that would let me **in one call** add or remove a user from a team

Is this something that I can do already using the above URL's ? I could not figure out how

If not, from [for example this page](https://www.mscharhag.com/api-design/rest-one-to-many-relations), it seems like a reasonable idea to define

- `/api/teams/<pk>/users/<pk>` (or something to that effect) which, according to PUT or DELETE, would add or remove one user from a team

I was kind of expecting these API calls to be generated for me by DRF, but currently it appears not (I'm using `manage.py show_urls` to inspect that)

What is the simplest/recommended way to implement this type of API calls with DRF ?

Comment: In the one call approach, did you mean you want to just override whatever user ids are in the team with the request you are building? Say if the team has 1, 2 and 3 and your request has 4, 5, 6, just overwrite? How will the client know where those user ids come from without the 1st call to get the current content?

Comment: at that point the application knows the set of possible candidates already; I do not want to overwrite, I want to perform a union; in your example the outcome would be all 6 students in the 1..6 range to belong; I have been able to implement that kind of behaviour 'manually', i.e. by writing a specific view, but this felts like something quite generic so I was looking for a more general way to achieve that same result

Comment: btw I went for a slightly different url scheme, my specific view is bound to `/api/teams/<pk>/users` and the set of ids to add or remove is passed in the request, using `PUT` or `DELETE` to select between addition or removal

Comment: One approach I see is to include the team FK in the user data on `POST` for `/api/users/` when creating a user or `PUT` on `/api/users/<pk>/` when adding/removing a user from a team. But if you want to also achieve the way it was done in the link you provided, you can use [DRF nested routers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#drf-nested-routers) [(git)](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers). It's another library that is not part of DRF, but endorsed